# How can I make this slider smoother?

Tags: jquery, slider, fade

Take a look at the front-page slider found here:

http://wildwoodtreeservices.wordpress.redcow.ca/

As you can see its *functional* in that it transitions from image to image, and the circle that matches the corresponding images changes to a different color... my only issue with it is that it isn't **smooth**. The images load in an ugly fashion leaving you to see the background image for a split second instead of the image itself.

Is there any way to make a fadeIn / fadeOut transition smooth so they don't see any background? Do I have to cache all 11 images on page-load or something?

Thanks in advance

My JS:

```
<script>
    var sliderpics = [];
    sliderpics[0] = "/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/slider1.jpg";
    sliderpics[1] = "/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/slider2.jpg";
    sliderpics[2] = "/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/slider3.jpg";
    sliderpics[3] = "/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/slider4.jpg";
    sliderpics[4] = "/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/slider5.jpg";
    sliderpics[5] = "/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/slider6.jpg";
    sliderpics[6] = "/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/slider7.jpg";
    sliderpics[7] = "/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/slider8.jpg";
    sliderpics[8] = "/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/slider9.jpg";
    sliderpics[9] = "/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/slider10.jpg";
    sliderpics[10] = "/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/slider11.jpg";

    var currentImage = 0;
    var currentCircle = 0;

    function changeSliderImage() {
        currentImage++;
        currentCircle++;
        if(currentImage > 10) currentImage = 0;
        if(currentCircle > 10) currentCircle = 0;

        $("#sliderpic").fadeOut(200, function() {
            $(this).attr("src",sliderpics[currentImage]);
            $("#circle" + currentCircle).attr("src","/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/circle_active.png");
            $("#circle" + (currentCircle - 1)).attr("src","/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/circle_inactive.png");
            if(currentCircle == 0){
                $("#circle10").attr("src","/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/circle_inactive.png");
            }
        });
        $("#sliderpic").fadeIn(200);

        setTimeout(changeSliderImage, 5000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function($) {
        setTimeout(changeSliderImage, 5000);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: dont blame the image cache. if it was the cache, that effect should go away the 2nd time the slideshow looped from start. But, it still has the same effect. So this is how it meant to be done.

Comment: I don't really know much about the image cache. I'm just wondering why it isn't "fading in" and "fading out" as it should be... it's doing ugly-image-load style :(

Comment: there is no "Should" there is only "how is programmed" and this is how its programmed. it has a complete fadeout of 200ms, a fadein of 200ms and a timeout of 2000ms. See code near the end of markup

Comment: so what should I make the fadein and fadeout timers? the same as the settimeout timers?

Comment: not working at all on my end.

Answer (score 1):

I'd swap your fadeOut and fadeIn, and alternate between two images:

HTML:

```
<img id="sliderpic0" class="sliderpic" alt="slider pic 1" src="[src]" style="display: inline;">
<img id="sliderpic1" class="sliderpic" alt="slider pic 1" src="[src]" style="display: inline;">
```

Javascript:

```
function changeSliderImage(bleh) {
    currentImage++;
    currentCircle++;
    if(currentImage > 10) currentImage = 0;
    if(currentCircle > 10) currentCircle = 0;

    var elemone = (bleh) ? $("#sliderpic0") : $("#sliderpic1");
    var elemtwo = (bleh) ? $("#sliderpic1") : $("#sliderpic0");

    $(elemone).fadeIn(200);
    $(elemtwo).fadeOut(200, function() {
        $(this).attr("src",sliderpics[currentImage]);
        $("#circle" + currentCircle).attr("src","/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/circle_active.png");
        $("#circle" + (currentCircle - 1)).attr("src","/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/circle_inactive.png");
        if(currentCircle == 0){
            $("#circle10").attr("src","/wp-content/themes/REDCOW-WP/circle_inactive.png");
        }
    });

    setTimeout(changeSliderImage(!bleh), 2000);
}
```

Really quick brain-splat, should solve your problem! :)

EDIT:
Oh, and change your document.ready function to look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    setTimeout(changeSliderImage(true), 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why re-invent the wheel? Try [this jquery plugin](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/), it has a tonne of configurable options and has good browser support.

Comment: my boss has informed me that I'm to do it from scratch. Also, added my JS above.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd suggest having a look at the plugin anyway to see how they do it. The images are on the page in html to begin with so there's no delay with the animation as all the images are already loaded, which would prevent one issue. Also as Martin mentioned, switch the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` around